# Coordinate multiple generic constructor arguments

Tags: scala, generics, types

I'm trying to do something in Scala that I'm not sure is possible. I'd love some feedback from the community.

Say I have a sealed trait for some 'thing', a few concrete extensions of it, and a generic class which works with some implementation of that trait..

```
sealed trait Thing
class CoolThing extends Thing
class OtherThing extends Thing

class BoxOfThings[T <: Thing]
```

Now, I can define another class which handles two 'boxes of things' like so..

```
class PairOfBoxes(boxOne: BoxOfThings[_ <: Thing], boxTwo: BoxOfThings[_ <: Thing])
```

However, here it's perfectly fine to create a `PairOfBoxes` with one box of `CoolThing`s and the other of `OtherThing`s. I would like to declare that `boxOne` and `boxTwo` contain the same type of `Thing`.. is that at all possible?

For example:

```
// Cool things..
val boxOfCoolThings = new BoxOfThings[CoolThing]
val anotherBoxOfCoolThings = new BoxOfThings[CoolThing]
// Other things..
val boxOfOtherThings = new BoxOfThings[OtherThing]

// A pair of cool boxes, no problem:
new PairOfBoxes(boxOfCoolThings, anotherBoxOfCoolThings)

// A pair of different boxes, compiles but I don't want it to:
new PairOfBoxes(boxOfOtherThings, anotherBoxOfCoolThings)
```

I could do this by making the `PairOfBoxes` generic itself, like so..

```
class TypedPairOfBoxes[T <: BoxOfThings[_ <: Thing]](boxOne: T, boxTwo: T)
```

It works, but it's ugly..

```
// A pair of cool boxes, no problem:
new TypedPairOfBoxes[BoxOfThings[CoolThing]](boxOfCoolThings, anotherBoxOfCoolThings)

// A pair of different boxes, doesn't compile:
val mixedPair = new TypedPairOfBoxes[BoxOfThings[CoolThing]](boxOfOtherThings, anotherBoxOfCoolThings)
```

I would like to avoid this is I can. It pushes the problem upstream and forces us to specify the contents of each `TypedPairOfBoxes`. It would be ideal to simply use an untyped `PairOfBoxes` which asserts it's parameters are of the same type.

Possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to write as:

```
class TypedPairOfBoxes[T <: Thing](one: BoxOfThings[T], two: BoxOfThings[T])
```

Then:

```
scala> new TypedPairOfBoxes(boxOfOtherThings, anotherBoxOfCoolThings)
<console>:15: error: type mismatch;
 found   : BoxOfThings[OtherThing]
 required: BoxOfThings[Thing]
Note: OtherThing <: Thing, but class BoxOfThings is invariant in type T.
You may wish to define T as +T instead. (SLS 4.5)
              new TypedPairOfBoxes(boxOfOtherThings, anotherBoxOfCoolThings)
                                   ^
<console>:15: error: type mismatch;
 found   : BoxOfThings[CoolThing]
 required: BoxOfThings[Thing]
Note: CoolThing <: Thing, but class BoxOfThings is invariant in type T.
You may wish to define T as +T instead. (SLS 4.5)
              new TypedPairOfBoxes(boxOfOtherThings, anotherBoxOfCoolThings)
                                                     ^

scala> new TypedPairOfBoxes(boxOfCoolThings, anotherBoxOfCoolThings)
res3: TypedPairOfBoxes[CoolThing] = TypedPairOfBoxes@2f5e1167
```

Comment: Great, can you please provide an explanation of why this works?

Answer (score 0):

**I <3 Scala**

Scala can infer the generic types such that I can define an 'ugly' typed class but don't need to specify the specific implementation when I use it.

With this realization, I was able to define a typed class similar to the one in my question above..

`class TypedPairOfBoxes[T, BoxOfThings[T <: Thing]](boxOne: BoxOfThings[T], boxTwo: BoxOfThings[T])`

.. it looks a bit gnarly, but can be used as simply as this:

```
// Both boxes contain cool things, no problem:
new TypedPairOfBoxes(boxOfCoolThings, anotherBoxOfCoolThing)

// These boxes contain different things, doesn't compile:
new TypedPairOfBoxes(boxOfOtherThings, anotherBoxOfCoolThing)
```

Amazing.

**Edit:**

As @Eastsun demonstrated, the latter part of of the generic definition is unused. So can be written, instead, as:

```
class TypedPairOfBoxes[T <: Thing](boxOne: BoxOfThings[T], boxTwo: BoxOfThings[T])
```

This looks very much like Java. But the amazing thing here being that Scala infers the generic types from the parameters.

Comment: I'm going to leave this open for a while. Can this can be done even cleaner?